# IllegalArgumentException when app start post backpressed

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-ktx

I use "by viewModels" kotlin delegate for get some view model:

```
val viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory by lazy { ViewModelFactory.getInstance(this) }

val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels { viewModelFactory }
```

ViewModelFactory:

```
class ViewModelFactory private constructor(activity: AppCompatActivity) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(activity, null) {
private val application = activity.application

// DataSource
private val appDataSource: AppDataSourceImpl by lazy { AppDataSourceImpl(application) }

// Intercator 
private val appDataInteractor: AppDataInteractor by lazy {
    AppDataInteractor(appDataSource, userDataSource)
}

companion object {
    private var instance: ViewModelFactory? = null
    fun getInstance(activity: AppCompatActivity): ViewModelFactory {
        return instance ?: ViewModelFactory(activity).also {
            instance = it
        }
    }
}

override fun <T : ViewModel> create(
    key: String,
    modelClass: Class<T>,
    handle: SavedStateHandle
): T {
    return when {
        MainViewModel::class.java.isAssignableFrom(modelClass) -> {
            modelClass.getConstructor(AppDataInteractor::class.java, SavedStateHandle::class.java)
               .newInstance(appDataInteractor, handle)
        }
        else -> throw Exception("Unknown ViewModel $modelClass")
    }
}

}
```

When app was closed by backpressed and launched again, it throws exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered."

I see two solutions to resolve the problem.
First is use exitProcess() instead of super.onBackPressed(). It is worked.

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isOpen) drawerLayout.close()
        else {
            if (navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.nav_homeFragment) {
            exitProcess(1) //super.onBackPressed()
           }
        else navController.navigateUp()
     }
    }
```

Second is transfer my viewmodel from activity to application. In the case there are survive after destroying activity. But i can`t use "by viewModels" kotlin delegate in application. I think it is not right solution (but it work too).

Where is the right way to get viewmodels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `ViewModelFactory.getInstance(this)` method - it is caching the `ViewModelFactory` as a static instance that survives the destruction of the activity itself. Besides leaking the activity itself, it means that the second time your activity is created, the `ViewModelFactory` that is returned is still associated with the first, already destroyed activity.

By using `by lazy`, you're already ensuring that the code runs only once for the lifetime of the activity, so you should remove the `instance` variable and the caching within `getInstance` entirely.